# Как получить список чатов для разных пользователей?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Я разрабатываю приложения чата. У меня имеются следующие таблицы в моей базе данных MySQL:

**USERS:**
[ id, username, email ]

**CHAT_ROOMS:**
[id, created_at, updated_at ]

**CHAT_ROOM_USER:**
[ id, user_id, chat_room_id ]

**MESSAGES:**
[ id, sender_id, message, created_at, updated_at ]

Как мне вывести список чатов для каждого пользователя, где в качестве заголовка чата будет имя собеседника?
Я делаю такой запрос, он мне возращает последние сообщения из чатов каждого пользователя, но как мне выводить еще и username собеседника? Мне кажется это должен быть какой-то подзапрос?

Мой запрос:

```
SELECT chat_rooms.id,messages.message AS 'last_message', messages.created_at FROM chat_room_user 
JOIN chat_rooms ON chat_room_user.chat_room_id = chat_rooms.id 
JOIN users ON chat_room_user.user_id = users.id JOIN messages ON chat_room_user.chat_room_id = messages.chat_room_id 
WHERE users.id = $user_id 
AND messages.id IN (SELECT MAX(messages.id) FROM messages GROUP BY messages.chat_room_id) ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC;
```

**UPD**

Результат, который я получаю сейчас согласно моему запросу, однако в поле title находится имя текущего пользователя, а нужно имя собеседника. Например, если у пользователя user_1 есть чат с user_2 и чат с user_3, то в поле title мне нужно получить именно user_2 и user_3, т.е имена моих собеседников а не мое имя. Надеюсь я достаточно подробно описал мою проблему

```
"chat_rooms": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "user_1",
            "message_id": 24,
            "last_message": "Hello",
            "updated_at": null,
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "user_1",
            "message_id": 21,
            "last_message": "Голосовое сообщение",
            "updated_at": "2022-07-27 15:50:03",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ]
```

Comment: В запросе уже есть `JOIN users` , почему из него нельзя вывести username?

Comment: Потому что выводится текущий юзер, а нужно выводить тех, с кем у текущего чат

Comment: а как нужно `выводить тех, с кем у текущего чат` ? Насколько понял, в чате может быть много пользователей, нужно вывести первого попавшегося собеседника или всех списком? Нужно ли этих пользователей сортировать по какому-то критерию?

Comment: Чат может быть только между двумя пользователями. Мне нужно получить список (массив) чатов пользователя по его ID со солеюущими полями:
id (чата), title (имя собеседника в чате), last_message (последнее сообщение в чате), message_id (id этого самого последнего сообщения в чате). И отсортировать по дате создания сообщения (messages.created_at). Мой запрос возвращает все чт омне нужно, кроме имени собеседника, я не знаю как его получить согласно моей структуре таблиц

Comment: Я обновлю вопрос, добавив JSON который я получаю сейчас, применяя мой запрос, указанный выше. Еще раз подчеркну, он мне возвращает все что нужно, кроме имени собеседника, которое должно быть под ключем title (сейчас тут имя  самого пользователя)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пользователей всегда два, то можно его выводить вместо текущего

- в подзапросе получаем список чатов для текущего пользователя `chat_rooms.id IN`
- поскольку в чате всего 2 пользователя, то исключаем текущего и останется второй пользователь чата, делаем через <> `users.id <> $user_id`

Отредактированный запрос:

```
SELECT chat_rooms.id,
       messages.message AS 'last_message',
       messages.created_at,
       users.username --тут будет собеседник
FROM chat_room_user
         JOIN chat_rooms ON chat_room_user.chat_room_id = chat_rooms.id
         JOIN users ON chat_room_user.user_id = users.id
         JOIN messages ON chat_room_user.chat_room_id = messages.chat_room_id
WHERE users.id <> $user_id
  AND chat_rooms.id IN (SELECT chat_room_id FROM chat_room_user WHERE user_id = $user_id)
  AND messages.id IN (SELECT MAX(messages.id) FROM messages GROUP BY messages.chat_room_id)
ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Спасибо, кажется это решило мою проблему